# How to extract data from bz2 file without decompress the file

Tags: linux

I want to perform the following command in a compressed file (.bz2). I typed the following:

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt.bz2 > output.txt
```

But the result is: Killed. How can I extract portion of the compressed text file I have without decompress it as it is extremely large file and I do not have enough space?

Comment: have a look at avfs also : http://avf.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must decompress it. You don't need to decompress it to disk.

```
bzcat input.txt.bz2 | awk '{print $1}' > output.txt
```

Comment: you can use bzgrep also